# Translation of "for whom" or "to whom"

Tags: grammar, translation

How would you translate the following sentences?
1/ Check the identity of any other person for whom you may have requested an extra card.
2/ She is the person to whom I sent the documents.

I always struggle when I have to translate "for whom" or "to whom".
On the web, I found "添付ファイルを送る相手" to translate "person to whom one sends the attachment".
Is this translation acceptable ? If I am correct, this may also mean "the person (or party) who sends the attachment". So I am really confused.

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this falls into the area of appositives/relative clauses, as in the example you gave, but you can be tricky and get a little more specificity out of it:

送信した添付ファイルの宛先 <- explicit

代わりに（代表として）カードを要求した本人<-　explicit>のアイデンティティを確認してください

I am confident in the first one, but you should bounce the second one off someone else, too.

Comment: I see ! Thank you very much for your answer.
I guess my mistake was to try translating word for word.

This is very useful, thanks again.